# Problems installing 16.04 in dual boot with Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows

I have a desktop with Windows 10 installed.  I've added a new drive (an M.2) so I can dual boot with Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.

Here's the setup:

- `/dev/sda` is an SSD with Windows 10 on it.
- `/dev/sdb` is an old HDD that's currently the Win10 "D:" drive
- `/dev/sdc` is the new M.2 drive that I want to install Ubuntu on.

The Ubuntu install goes fine until we have to install grub, at which point it fails with "unable to install grub in /dev/sda".  My options are to install to a different drive, continue without grub, or cancel.  Trying to change to a different drive just doesn't work: I can change the drive from the dropdown but the "ok" button doesn't do anything.  I eventually have to abort the install.

Same results if I start with "Install Ubuntu" or if I load the Live CD then try the install from there (as some people have suggested to other people's posts).

Comment: Is Windows installed in UEFI or BIOS boot mode? And then are you installing Ubuntu on sdc in same boot mode? If Ubuntu is in UEFI mode, you must have ESP - efi system partition on sda. If installing in BIOS mode and sda is gpt partitioned you must have a bios_grub partition for grub to install, but better to install in UEFI boot mode. Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: I'll double check, but I'm 99% sure it's in BIOS (old style) mode.

Answer (score 1):

Well that was an adventure...  but I got it working.

I had to do a whole afternoon's worth of stuff, but I think the short answer is that I had to enable EFI in the BIOS before I could install GRUB to the Windows (/dev/sda) drive.  You would think that having EFI/UEFI/Secure Boot or anything of that ilk turned off would allow me to freely install stuff..

Prior to this fix, though, I also updated my motherboard's BIOS firmware.  I mention this in case other users also need to do the same.  After updating the firmware I found that (in Windows) my ethernet controller needed new drivers (no network connection) so I had to run back and forth from my Windows machine to my other Ubuntu machine with a USB stick to download then transfer the necessary files.  Besides the ethernet controller drivers I also sneaker-netted anything else that looked interesting, but the NIC drivers were the big issue.

So once I had Windows working right (with EFI turned on in the BIOS) I tried reinstalling Ubuntu 16.10 from scratch on the M.2 drive (/dev/sdc).  This time around it went through without a hitch.  I held my breath while it was installing GRUB but it made it through.

So thanks to everyone who contributed here.  This install was more work that it should have been but still a learning experience.

Now to configure the Ubuntu side the way I like it....

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem for weeks, So you want to get both OS's installed. Then boot into Live version of Ubuntu and you need to pretty much repair the windows partition.

So I followed this guide http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd

Then it works, let me know if this helps

Comment: So you installed Ubuntu without grub, then repaired afterwards?

Comment: yes, while I was getting same error as you, so I check the "do something else" on install and created my own partition table then installed grub on windows partition and linux

Comment: Sorry I took so long to respond..  

So far, no luck.  I've tried installing Ubuntu 16.10, 16.04, even Fedora from USB.  I even went and dug up an old DVD drive and tried installing from a DVD.  Always the same thing: it fails to install GRUB, then the installation exits out.  There's no way to get it to continue, so I couldn't do your idea of doing the install then going back and repairing GRUB.
I went into the computer's BIOS and make sure that EFI and Secure Boot, and Fast Boot were completely off.

I appreciate your efforts so far, sorry if I seem a bit negative here...